# ncat ssl-connection with username/password authentication?

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, passwords, nmap

Can someone show me with ncat, how to connect to a https URL where the server requires a username+password?

Without user+password
I can connect with just

```
  ncat --ssl host port
```

but how do I specify logon-credentials, when required?

Answer (score 1):

You pass the header `Authorization: Basic BASE64_ENCODED('username:password')`

Literally `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQNCg==`